# I'm trying to find happy numbers but my program goes into an endless loop

Tags: python

I've done everything in my ability to try to do this without any functions and only while loops (as said by my teacher) please could you find out why, I even tried dry running but it should still work
p.s it doesn't work in either ways of using:
`while c!=0 and f<50:` or `while c!0 or f<50:`

```
happy_num=1
x= [0]*30
f=0
#f is a safety measure so that the program has a stop and doesnt go out of control
happynumbers=" "
number=int(input("input number "))

while happy_num!=31:
    c=0
    happy=number
    while c!=1 or f<50:
        integer=number
        f=f+1
        if integer<10:
            a=number
            b=0
            d=0
        elif integer<100:
            a=number // 10
            b=number % 10
            d=0
        else:
            a=number // 10
            bee=number % 100
            b=bee // 10
            d=number % 10


        number=(a*a)+(b*b)+(d*d)
        c=number
    x[happy_num-1]=happy



    if c==1:
        happy_num+=1
    elif f>49:
        print("too many iterations program shutting down")
        exit()
    number=happy+1
print ("the happy numbers are: ", happynumbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you say:

> It doesn't work in either ways of using: `while c!=1 and f<50:` or `while c!=1 or f<50`

You should use the one with `and` (`while c!=1 and f<50:`), because otherwise it is useless as a failsafe. Right now your program gets stuck anyways so it might seem to you to not make a difference, I understand that. It's important in general that a failsafe is added with `and`, and not with `or` (because `true or true == true` and `true or false == true`, so when your loop is infinite, the `f<50` failsafe will not make any difference to the truth value of the guard).

Adding print statements to your program, you can see that at around `f=30` the program starts to become very slow, but this is not because of some infinite loop or anything; it's because the computations start to become very big at the line:

```
number=(a*a)+(b*b)+(d*d)
```

So `f` never actually reaches `50`, because the program gets stuck trying to perform enormous multiplications. So much for your failsafe :/

I am not sure what algorithm you are using to find these happy numbers, but my guess it that there is something lacking in your guard of the inner loop, or some break statement missing. Do you account for the situation that the number isn't a happy number? Somehow you should also exit the loop in that situation. If you have some more background to what the program is supposed to do, that would be very helpful.

**Edit**: judging from the [programming example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Programming_example) on the Wikipedia page of happy numbers, you need some way to keep track of which numbers you've already 'visited' during your computations; that is the only way to know that some number is *not* a happy number.

Answer (score 0):

plus the question i was given was to find the first 30 happy numbers, so the input would 1

Comment: You should edit your question directly instead of adding an answer here.